# Keeping an independent ID Counter inside Class Object in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, database, arraylist

I apologize that I don't know much programming, but I'm trying to learn by experimenting in Java right now. I'm being very ambitious by attempting to program a desktop app that will as well, in the future become a web application. And of course, I would like for the 2 applications to sync up with each other.

I am imagining, let's say .. Task List Keeper. For the web application, I will use MySQL for the database. However in my desktop app, I am imagining that I would use ArrayList for the database. (Or is there a way that I should use some Java DB instead of classes?)

If I am going down the wrong path currently, I am in the infancy of developing this, so I can change course easily. But essentially, I have a class Task, and a class Database to hold the Tasks.

In my thoughts of trying to keep a consistent ID that will pair with the MySQL record, I am attempting to store a taskID. I have gotten something to work, but I also don't think it's the best solution. I'm just seeing if anyone can point me in the different, and more efficient direction that I could look into and/or should try.

Here is the code that I have compiled thus far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Todos {

    public static class Database {
        private ArrayList<Task> database = new ArrayList<Task>();
        private int taskCounter = 0;

        /*
        // This above taskCounter is not being incremented inside my
        // addTask method, so I had put the for-loop in there..

        public boolean addTask(Task task)
        {
            boolean addItemSuccessful = false;
            int originalArraySize = database.size();
            taskCounter++;
            database.add(task);
            if (database.size() > originalArraySize)
            {
                addItemSuccessful = true;
            }
            return addItemSuccessful;
        }
        */

        public boolean addTask(Task task)
        {
            boolean addItemSuccessful = false;
            int originalArraySize = database.size();
            int taskID = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++) {
                if (database.get(i).taskID > taskID) {
                    taskID = database.get(i).taskID;
                    System.out.println(taskID);
                }
            }
            taskID++;
            task.setTaskID(taskID);
            System.out.println(taskID);
            database.add(task);
            if (database.size() > originalArraySize)
            {
                addItemSuccessful = true;
            }
            return addItemSuccessful;
        }

        public boolean removeTask(int taskID) {
            // This code is actually not correct, here but this is the idea.
            boolean removeItemSuccessful = false;
            int originalArraySize = database.size();
            database.remove(taskID);
            if (database.size() < originalArraySize)
            {
                removeItemSuccessful = true;
            }
            return removeItemSuccessful;
        }

    }

    public static class Task {

        private int taskID;
        private String task;
        private Priority priority = Priority.ZERO;

        public enum Priority { ZERO, MAYBE, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, EXTREME }

        public void setTaskID(int taskID) {
            this.taskID = taskID;
        }
        // .. Other Getters and Setters for Task
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Database database = new Database();
        Task newTask = new Task();

        database.addTask(newTask);  // Add 1st Task, taskID = 1
        database.addTask(newTask);  // Add 2nd Task, taskID = 2
        database.addTask(newTask);  // Add 3rd Task, taskID = 3
        database.removeTask(2);     // Remove Task 2
        database.addTask(newTask);  // Add 4th Task, taskID = 4

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered letting the database chose the ID with an auto-increment field instead, then putting it in the object after you've saved it?

Comment: @MrLore, thanks for the idea! I will look into this! Im such a novice, I don't know too many available options, I am just going from my base understandings. So Thank you, I will definitely look into this.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement the repository pattern. See http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html and http://moleseyhill.com/blog/2009/07/13/active-record-verses-repository/ and http://moleseyhill.com/blog/2009/06/29/simple-repository-pattern/ (even though it's not Java).

Comment: You might want to use an embeddable DB like [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) for your standalone application. This will bring both the standalone and web application code bases very close to being the same.

Comment: Since this is more of an 'opinion' discussion, recommend moving it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. It's the perfect venue for these types of questions.

Comment: great ideas guys, and @cmonkey, you're right about moving it to codereview, i will think about posting there next time I have a question like this. As with this too, I don't know my options as well, glad for the education today.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a new entry in a database, the db automatically assigns an auto-increment ID (I think you can also choose yours but you shouldn't). If you don't have a specific reason, i suggest you not to include it among the fields of `Task`, and use it instead as index to access and positioning in your `ArrayList`, or possibly do it more explicitly with a `HashMap <Integer, Task>`. Else you can create a static field to generate your auto-Incremental ID or continue on your way.